# Coins in pocket probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In total there are 10 coins:

- **5**: 50 cent coins
- **4**: 10 cent coins
- **1**: 5 cent coin

What is the probability that 3 randomly selected coins do not exceed €1?

This is my approach:

$$P = 1 -\frac{\binom{5}3 + \binom{5}2 \binom{5}1 }{\binom{10}3} = \frac{1}2$$

Is this correct?

**Reasoning:**

If one is to select at least two 50 cent coins it would exceed 1€.

Comment: The winning scenarios are just the ones in which you get at most $1$ fifty cent piece.  You can either add the two good cases (no fifty cent piece, exactly one fifty cent piece) or you can subtract the two bad cases from $1$.

Comment: You should explain the reasoning behind your answer.  No, it is not correct.

Comment: What you wrote is incorrect.  You are trying to combine the two bad cases into one, but it doesn't work.  You are overcounting the cases with $3$ fifty cent coins.

Comment: This would be my approach:$$\frac{\binom 53+\binom51\binom52}{\binom {10}3}.$$

Comment: You also have to subtract the case in which all three coins are 50 cent coins.

Comment: Yes, your answer is now correct.